# How do I make node.js execute some code only if my file is the running file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I want to be able to start my express server directly via:

```
$ node app.js
```

But I also want to able to require that file, and have it return the app instance but actually not start the server.  Then I can start later it with some options.

```
app = require './app'
app.listen options.someCustomPort
```

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of this ruby snippet, but in node.js.

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  app.listen options[:some_custom_port]
end
```

Is there an idiom for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check

```
module.parent
```

If it's `null` or `undefined`, you're the main file. If not, you've been `require`d. Your `module.parent` is the `module` object of the module that `require`d you.

Comment: Perfect. Also, if I may, the speed at which you attack any coffeescript tagged questions is staggering.  How do you do that?

Comment: In an astonishingly old-fashioned way: I keep http://stackoverflow.com/tags/coffeescript open in a tab, and every hour or so that I'm at my computer, I hit refresh.

Comment: Odd, could this have changed recently? Today's `node` assigns `module.parent` to `null`, not `undefined` in such cases

Comment: @EliBendersky Yes, it would appear that it's `null` now. Not sure when that changed.